# How do I make my python code distributable?

Tags: python, path, share, project

I have made a hardcoded voice assistant in python. https://github.com/Sneakyhydra/JARVIS
Now I want to make it distributable to others but the apps that are in the users folder have my username in their paths. So no one else can open them. I am still in the learning phase of python and this is my first ever project. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio code, just open that file and copy the whole code and delete that file and make another file and click on open in code the your visual studio code will be open in that folder and you can just create a main.py and paste the code there. I was also suffering from the same problem and I did something like this.